# What exactly does !default do in CSS?

Tags: css

I am having a hard time finding anything about `!default`. It's not the most search friendly term.

Comment: Stack Overflow's search engine recognizes special characters, just quote it: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+%22%21default%22

Comment: there's no such thing as !default in css.